# Install Tensorflow on Application running on Openshift 3.5

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, openshift

I have created a demo account on manage.openshift.com and an application starting from python 2.7 image.

I have pushed a requirements.txt with inside tensorflow dependency and started a build.

I've got this error in my build's log:

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip==9.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Collecting tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/python-27-rhel7@sha256:69cc225a61cec131f43915ba3cd26edf3692d0d53f9a2df4eba5ed6f70410cdc
```

How should I proceed in order to update pip and install tensorflow?

Comment: Are these just Docker containers? Can you base yours on the [official TensorFlow docker builds](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tensorflow` package may be somehow incompatible with the older `pip` version. On the build configuration for your application on OpenShift, add an environment variable:

```
UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1
```

Alternatively, in your Git repo, add a file `.s2i/environment` and stick the environment variable setting in that.

That environment variable should force the S2I builder to upgrade pip before it installs any packages in your `requirements.txt` file.

The only other possibility is that you are using pinned versions in your `requirements.txt` file and some version tag for something is wrong and causing issues.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I was missing the chance to specify to UPGRADE_PIP . Is there a page where I can find similar parameters?